# Java SpringBoot MySQL, AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance Deployment, EntityNotFoundException, Unable to connect to MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have deployed a Java SpringBoot project utilizing AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance and am receiving the error:

Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception: jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException

I am new to AWS deployment and this is my first time using it, so I am unsure where to even begin in finding the cause for the error. The nature of the error leads me to believe that the server cannot communicate with MySQL. I presume that is due to a missing/improper security group within my EC2 instance, or a missing connection from MySQL to the server. Attached is the relevant code:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.anthony.messagingapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MessagingApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MessagingApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liaisonmessaging
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=rootroot
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

Application.java file

```
package com.anthony.messagingapp;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProtocol;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MessagingAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessagingAppApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        Connector ajpConnector = new Connector("AJP/1.3");
        ajpConnector.setPort(9090);
        ajpConnector.setSecure(false);
        ajpConnector.setAllowTrace(false);
        ajpConnector.setScheme("http");
((AbstractAjpProtocol)ajpConnector.getProtocolHandler()).setSecretRequired(false);
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(ajpConnector);
        return tomcat;

}
```

Inbound Security Groups on EC2 instance

1. Port Range: **9090**

- Type: TCP
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

2. Port Range: **80**

- Type: HTTP
- Source: ::/0

3. Port Range: **22**

- Type: SSH
- Source: My private IP

4. Port Range: **3306**

- MYSQL/Aurora
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

5. Port Range: **443**

- Type: HTTPS

6. Port Range: **9090**

- Type: TCP
- Source: ::/0

7. Port Range: **80**

- Type: HTTP
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

8. Port Range: **3306**

- Type: MYSQL/Aurora
- Source: ::/0

9. Port Range: **8888**

- Type: Custom TCP
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

My process to deploy is as follows:

1. Create instance with the following details:

- Ubuntu AMI, x64 bit architecture
- Instance Type: t2.micro
- Key Pair: RSA, .pem
- Allowing SSH traffic from my IP, HTTP & HTTPS traffic from the internet

2. SSH into the instance from my terminal

- update & upgrade dependencies

3. Install MySQL Server & connect

- sudo apt-get install mysql-server
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo mysql -uroot -p
- within sql shell: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '*mysql_password*';
- within sql shell: FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
- outside of sql shell: sudo mysql_secure_installation
- I then configure security settings
- Finally, I export my database into a dump file, and then paste the contents of the dump file in the sql shell in the server

4. Install Apache

- sudo apt-get install apache2

5. Create a .war file of my SpringBoot application and secure copy it into my instance
6. Create proxy in server

- sudo a2enmod proxy
- sudo a2enmod ajp-proxy

7. add ProxyPass into the virtual host conf file

- cd etc/apache2/sites-available
- sudo vim 000-default.conf
- INSERT ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:9090/
- INSERT ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:9090/

8. Restart Apache

- sudo service apache2 restart

9. Install Java JDK

- sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk

10. Run .war file

- java -jar MessagingApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

My application runs without issue when deployed on my local server, but runs with EntityNotFoundException when deployed and accessed through public AWS EC2 instance IP address. I confirmed in the terminal that the server is listening on port 80, and I am able to access the root route when requesting http://{PUBLIC.IP}
Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Notice the highlighted part from what you've mentioned
[image]

I don't think this is properly set.
First of of, the port should be 3306. I believe this is a typo, you might have set the port to 3306.
Yet there is another problem, you might want to set the rule like this: (assuming your ec2 secuirty group id is sg-1234abcd)

| MySQL/Aurora | TCP | 3306 | sg-1234abcd |

the source is 'sg-1234abcd', which means you want all ec2 in this security group have the permissions to access the mysql.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. I just edited the post to accurately reflect the current inbound rules on my EC2 instance. I have a rule for Port Range 3306 with type MYSQL/Aurora. Still to no avail.